XSLT split XML into separate messsages by child node
I'd like to split an XML message into separate messages, by each ocurence of a subnode (A_SalesOrderItemType), keeping the parent values for each via XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 transformation.
An excerpt of the XML file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A_SalesOrder>
    <A_SalesOrderType>
        <AdditionalValueDays>0</AdditionalValueDays>
        <CreationDate>2024-03-25T00:00:00.000</CreationDate>
        <to_Item>
            <A_SalesOrderItemType>
                <SalesOrderItemText>1</SalesOrderItemText>
                <AdditionalValueDays>0</AdditionalValueDays>
                <to_ScheduleLine>
                    <A_SalesOrderScheduleLineType>
                        <OpenConfdDelivQtyInOrdQtyUnit>1000</OpenConfdDelivQtyInOrdQtyUnit>
                        <ScheduleLine>1</ScheduleLine>
                    </A_SalesOrderScheduleLineType>
                </to_ScheduleLine>
            </A_SalesOrderItemType>
            <A_SalesOrderItemType>
                <SalesOrderItemText>2</SalesOrderItemText>
                <AdditionalValueDays>0</AdditionalValueDays>
                <to_ScheduleLine>
                    <A_SalesOrderScheduleLineType>
                        <OpenConfdDelivQtyInOrdQtyUnit>2000</OpenConfdDelivQtyInOrdQtyUnit>
                        <ScheduleLine>1</ScheduleLine>
                    </A_SalesOrderScheduleLineType>
                </to_ScheduleLine>
            </A_SalesOrderItemType>
        </to_Item>
    </A_SalesOrderType>
    <A_SalesOrderType>
        <AdditionalValueDays>0</AdditionalValueDays>
        <CreationDate>2024-03-25T00:00:00.000</CreationDate>
        <to_Item>
            <A_SalesOrderItemType>
                <SalesOrderItemText>3</SalesOrderItemText>
                <AdditionalValueDays>0</AdditionalValueDays>
                <to_ScheduleLine>
                    <A_SalesOrderScheduleLineType>
                        <OpenConfdDelivQtyInOrdQtyUnit>3000</OpenConfdDelivQtyInOrdQtyUnit>
                        <ScheduleLine>1</ScheduleLine>
                    </A_SalesOrderScheduleLineType>
                </to_ScheduleLine>
            </A_SalesOrderItemType>
            <A_SalesOrderItemType>
                <SalesOrderItemText>4</SalesOrderItemText>
                <AdditionalValueDays>0</AdditionalValueDays>
                <to_ScheduleLine>
                    <A_SalesOrderScheduleLineType>
                        <OpenConfdDelivQtyInOrdQtyUnit>4000</OpenConfdDelivQtyInOrdQtyUnit>
                        <ScheduleLine>1</ScheduleLine>
                    </A_SalesOrderScheduleLineType>
                </to_ScheduleLine>
            </A_SalesOrderItemType>
        </to_Item>
    </A_SalesOrderType>
</A_SalesOrder>

Desired output
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A_SalesOrder>
    <A_SalesOrderType>
        <AdditionalValueDays>0</AdditionalValueDays>
        <CreationDate>2024-03-25T00:00:00.000</CreationDate>
        <to_Item>
            <A_SalesOrderItemType>
                <SalesOrderItemText>1</SalesOrderItemText>
                <AdditionalValueDays>0</AdditionalValueDays>
                <to_ScheduleLine>
                    <A_SalesOrderScheduleLineType>
                        <OpenConfdDelivQtyInOrdQtyUnit>1000</OpenConfdDelivQtyInOrdQtyUnit>
                        <ScheduleLine>1</ScheduleLine>
                    </A_SalesOrderScheduleLineType>
                </to_ScheduleLine>
            </A_SalesOrderItemType>
        </to_Item>
    </A_SalesOrderType>
    <A_SalesOrderType>
        <AdditionalValueDays>0</AdditionalValueDays>
        <CreationDate>2024-03-25T00:00:00.000</CreationDate>
        <to_Item>
            <A_SalesOrderItemType>
                <SalesOrderItemText>2</SalesOrderItemText>
                <AdditionalValueDays>0</AdditionalValueDays>
                <to_ScheduleLine>
                    <A_SalesOrderScheduleLineType>
                        <OpenConfdDelivQtyInOrdQtyUnit>2000</OpenConfdDelivQtyInOrdQtyUnit>
                        <ScheduleLine>1</ScheduleLine>
                    </A_SalesOrderScheduleLineType>
                </to_ScheduleLine>
            </A_SalesOrderItemType>
        </to_Item>
    </A_SalesOrderType>
.
.
.
</A_SalesOrder>

The XSLT transformation below works as expected, but is there a more elegant way than copying all parent elements manually?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                xmlns:map = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsl fo xs math fn map">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <!-- defines the format of the output document xml|html|text|name -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" />
    <!-- remove white space nodes -->
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <A_SalesOrder>
            <xsl:for-each select="A_SalesOrder/A_SalesOrderType/to_Item/A_SalesOrderItemType">
                <A_SalesOrderType>
                    <AdditionalValueDays>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../AdditionalValueDays" />
                    </AdditionalValueDays>
                    <CreationDate>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../CreationDate" />
                    </CreationDate>
                    <to_Item>
                        <A_SalesOrderItemType>
                            <SalesOrderItemText>
                                <xsl:value-of select="SalesOrderItemText" />
                            </SalesOrderItemText>
                            <AdditionalValueDays>
                                <xsl:value-of select="AdditionalValueDays" />
                            </AdditionalValueDays>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="to_ScheduleLine"/>
                        </A_SalesOrderItemType>
                    </to_Item>
                </A_SalesOrderType>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </A_SalesOrder>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


There are two types of XML 1) Well formed 2) Not well formed.  A well formed XML has only one root node.  Not well formed has an array of nodes at the root.  Most libraries you have to change properties to allow an array.

There is a snapshot function in XSLT 3 you could use if you just wanted the subtree containing a certain element but you seem to want to copy some preceding siblings as well so I think you need an approach like
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <A_SalesOrder>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="A_SalesOrder/A_SalesOrderType/to_Item/A_SalesOrderItemType" mode="split"/>
    </A_SalesOrder>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="A_SalesOrderItemType" mode="split">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::A_SalesOrderType">
      <xsl:with-param name="item" select="current()" tunnel="yes"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="A_SalesOrderItemType">
    <xsl:param name="item" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:if test=". is $item">
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Here is somewhat simpler XSLT.
XSLT
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/A_SalesOrder">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="A_SalesOrderType/to_Item/A_SalesOrderItemType">
                <xsl:sort select="A_SalesOrderItemType/SalesOrderItemText"/>
                <A_SalesOrderType>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="../../AdditionalValueDays"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="../../CreationDate"/>
                    <to_Item>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </to_Item>
                </A_SalesOrderType>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

